# Insert Space Between rows If date Is Different in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, asp.net-4.0, asp.net-4.5

I'm Stuck in Problem Where I Have a gridview I want to show space between rows If Date Is Different .

I Tried to add New Row But It Has Id Column and Company Id Column  Which Can not Be null. so Cant Add  new Row .

Now I tried to Add Space between Rows . Its working for all record but Do Not have Different Date condition.

What I Eventually want Is If date is same Then No space between Rows if Different then space.

This Will Give better readability Date wise.

Note Data is Group By sorted with Different Column

I'm using Mysql

Comment: How are you binding data? Stored Procedure? If you are using Stored Procedure then you can use `tally table` to create a calendar and join with that to get empty rows for non-available dates.

Comment: You can use this script for creating `calendar table` in `MySql` - http://www.brianshowalter.com/calendar_tables

Comment: What is the datasource of the grid?

Comment: different from the rest of the dates in the gridview?

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that you use a `DataTable` as `DataSource` for the GridView (works also with different sources in a similar way):

```
DataRow lastRow = null;
protected void GrdidView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataRow thisRow = ((DataRowView) e.Row.DataItem).Row;
        if(lastRow != null) // only add separators between two rows
        {
            DateTime thisDate = thisRow.Field<DateTime>("ColumnName");
            DateTime lastDate = lastRow.Field<DateTime>("ColumnName");
            if (thisDate.Date != lastDate.Date)
            {
                e.Row.Style.Add("border-top-width", "20px");
            }
        }
        lastRow = thisRow;
    }
}
```

Comment: Giving Exception  
Additional information: Specified cast is not valid.

I'm Using datetime for Date Column in database

Comment: @Morfious: _where_ do you get the exception?  I doubt that it's at `thisRow.Field<DateTime>("ColumnName")` if you really store it as `DateTime`. If you look at `e.Row.DataItem` in the debugger, what type is it? What do you assign as `DataSource`?

Comment: Hi,Tim

I used Your Code this way working fine For me.I did some alteration in Your code 

Now I have Got another problem because of this in my project.

Comment: Hi,Tim

I used Your Code this way working fine For me.I did some alteration in Your code 

Now I have Got another problem because of this in my project.
DataRow lastRow = null;

this Line is stopping my java script to run since row is empty. java script  on Button click event selected people by check box get approved and disapproved .since Datarow lastRow = null; nothing happens java script not working for  Row selected by checkbox

Answer (score 0):

If you use column templates in your GridView columns you can try this approach. On the GridView prerender event loop through the table to compare the dates.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" id="GridView" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
               <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Literal runat="server" id="ltDate" Text='<%#Bind("MyDate")%>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

private void GridView_PreRender(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    string sCompareDate = "";
    foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in GridView.Rows) {
        //First Row
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sCompareDate))
            sCompareDate = ((Literal)gvRow.FindControl("ltDate")).Text;

        if (sCompareDate != ((Literal)gvRow.FindControl("ltDate")).Text) {
            gvRow.Cells(0).Attributes.Add("style", "border-bottom-width:30px;");
            sCompareDate = ((Literal)gvRow.FindControl("ltDate")).Text;
    }
}
}
```